# What is `sparse sandbox` and `shared sandbox` in MKS Integrity

Tags: version-control, mks, mks-integrity

What do `Make Sandbox Sparse` and `Make Sandbox Shared` mean in [MKS Integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_Integrity)?

[image: MKS Integrity - Create Sandbox Wizard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparse: The sandbox-directory contains only the files not in sync with the repository. Resynchronise a sparse sandbox deletes all files from the directory that are in sync. (while resynchronising a non-sparse directory will cause the check out of all member-revisions)

Share: You can share this sandbox with other MKS-users. They can import the same sandbox and work on it (check-in, check-out).

You may change both settings in the Sandbox Information window of the (topmost) sandbox by (un)checking the check-box "Sparse" resp. "Shared". Doing so does not change any of your working files, just the behaviuor of some operations (e.g check-in)

Answer (score 0):

Sparse - if you do not want the Sandbox to retain working files when a member is checked in. A Sandbox is sparse if it has no working files. A sparse Sandbox does not retain working files when a member is checked in, and continues to function this way throughout its use; however, once created,Sandbox directories and sub Sandboxes remain in the Sandbox.

Shared - if you want multiple users to have access to the working files in the Sandbox.